# SWIG Identifier redefined (ignored) in templated function

Tags: c++, swig

I have read numerous other posts referring to swigs use of templates but have a unique issue with an example which I can reduce to a minimal case. E.g.

```
%include <stl.i>
%include <std_array.i>

%module example

%inline %{
template <typename T>  T ExampleFunc(){
    return (T)0;
}
template <typename T, unsigned int N>  std::array<T, N> ExampleFunc(){
    std::array<T, N> empty;
    return empty;
}
%}

%template(Int2) std::array<int, 2>;

%template(ExampleFuncInt) ExampleFunc<int>;
%template(ExampleFuncDouble) ExampleFunc<double>;
%template(ExampleFuncInt2) ExampleFunc<int, 2>;
```

The above produces the following warnings and errors when built using `swig -python -c++ example.i`

```
example.i(13) : Warning 302: Identifier 'ExampleFunc' redefined (ignored),
example.i(9) : Warning 302: previous definition of 'ExampleFunc'.
example.i(20) : Error: Template 'ExampleFunc' undefined.
```

I understand that this is because the two template functions have the signature without the template but in my real world example I need to template declare both a scalar and array version of the same function. Renaming the functions in the cpp library is not an option and using the `%rename` directive doesn't  work as this renames both versions of the function and produces the same warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
%include <stl.i>
%include <std_array.i>

%module example

%inline %{
template <typename T>  T ExampleFunc(){
    return (T)0;
}
template <>  std::array<int, 2> ExampleFunc(){
    std::array<int, 2> empty;
    return empty;
}
%}

%template(Int2) std::array<int, 2>;

%template(ExampleFuncInt2) ExampleFunc<std::array<int, 2>>;
%template(ExampleFuncInt) ExampleFunc<int>;
%template(ExampleFuncDouble) ExampleFunc<double>;
```

This works but with warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The template specialization doesn't need to be processed by SWIG, so I removed it from the `%inline` declaration, and added `#include <array>` so it would compile.

`ExampleFuncInt2`'s template declaration was wrong.  Also initialized `empty`.

This SWIGs with no warnings, and compiles @ /W3 with no warnings:

```
%module example

%{
#include <array>
%}

%inline %{
template <typename T>  T ExampleFunc(){
    return (T)0;
}
%}

%{
template <>  std::array<int, 2> ExampleFunc(){
    std::array<int, 2> empty{};
    return empty;
}
%}

%include <std_array.i>

%template(Int2) std::array<int, 2>;
%template(ExampleFuncInt) ExampleFunc<int>;
%template(ExampleFuncDouble) ExampleFunc<double>;
%template(ExampleFuncInt2) ExampleFunc<std::array<int, 2>>;
```

Demo:

```
>>> import example
>>> example.ExampleFuncInt()
0
>>> example.ExampleFuncDouble()
0.0
>>> example.ExampleFuncInt2()
(0, 0)
```